# Elastisearch Batch size limit

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 200 documents, and each document is 1 MB each. For a total 200MB, so want to index all of them in a batch at once, using bulk processing.

Is sending 200MB over the wire is too big for the elasticsearch to handle?

Answer (score 1):

Sending 200MB of data across the wire is going to take a very long time and will timeout your connection.  You'd be better off writing something that indexes 1 document at a time with maybe 5 concurrent threads.  Bulk inserting this much data will not really give you any benefit.

More generally, 1MB of data is ~500 pages of text.  I would argue that is WAY too much data to be putting into a single record in ES!  I think you're going to be disappointed with performance unless you've got a lot of horsepower, but that's going to be very expensive.  I recommend looking into making much smaller documents.